# Computer's RSA Fingerprint Debugging android

Tags: android, eclipse, rsa

I'm an Android developper, I've bought a used phone so I can test apps on it for screen compatibility issues.

When I've tried to connect it to my computer a dialog popped up saying that RSA numeric fingerprint of the computer is ... asking me if i should authorize it..

My question is, what does this key do? what's the purpose? does any of this get saved to google's servers?

Comment: That is simply a security feature by all Android versions 4.2.2+. It informs the user (you) when an unknown computer tries to access it.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what does this key do? what's the purpose?

Once upon a time, if a device had USB debugging enabled, any computer with the Android SDK could connect to the debugging tools on the device. This was really bad from a security standpoint.

Around Android 4.2 (IIRC), the dialog that you are referring to was added. Here, you are authorizing a debugging connection between your development machine and the device. Computers for which you have not accepted the dialog cannot use the debugging tools on the device. And, to accept the dialog, you need to have gotten past the lockscreen, which helps reduce the odds that an attacker will be able to click the dialog, because every developer has their lockscreen enabled with a good strong password (right?).

> does any of this get saved to google's servers?

Not that I am aware of.

Comment: I've bought this phone from an other dev. i'm afraid that if he get suspended that they link him to me or vice versa..

Comment: @daviddev38: I am not aware that the fingerprints used for debugging connections has any relationship to your Google accounts used for distribution on the Play Store. Moreover, please understand that the fingerprint is coming from the *computer*, not the phone. You are authorizing the *computer* to work with the phone for debugging purposes.